# How do I group by month for displaying dates in a Laravel blade?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am basically trying to achieve the following layout in a Laravel blade:

### October

17th
25th

### November

1st
13th

### December

16th

How do I get to this from having an array of dates, for example:

```
array (size=5)
'id' => int 1
'tour_id' => int 1
'start_date' => string '2014-10-17 00:00:00' (length=19)
'end_date' => string '2014-10-24 00:00:00' (length=19)
'price' => int 12503

array (size=5)
'id' => int 2
'tour_id' => int 1
'start_date' => string '2014-10-25 00:00:00' (length=19)
'end_date' => string '2014-10-31 00:00:00' (length=19)
'price' => int 12503

array (size=5)
'id' => int 3
'tour_id' => int 2
'start_date' => string '2014-11-01 00:00:00' (length=19)
'end_date' => string '2014-11-11 00:00:00' (length=19)
'price' => int 12503

array (size=5)
'id' => int 4
'tour_id' => int 3
'start_date' => string '2014-11-13 00:00:00' (length=19)
'end_date' => string '2014-11-31 00:00:00' (length=19)
'price' => int 12503

array (size=5)
'id' => int 5
'tour_id' => int 3
'start_date' => string '2014-12-16 00:00:00' (length=19)
'end_date' => string '2014-12-31 00:00:00' (length=19)
'price' => int 12503
```

I am returning this array to the view from my controller with the following line:

```
'tourDates' => $this->tourDate->all(['tour'], ['column' => 'start_date', 'order' => 'asc'])
```

Comment: You use `Carbon` which is built into Laravel -  https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon

Comment: I know that I need to use Carbon to get the string names for the months but it's more of how to group them by each month as I displayed above.

Comment: I would suggest you create somewhere in the background (not in the view itself; maybe in a helper class?) an array of the sort:

    $tourDates = [
                 'October' => [
                                 '17',
                                 '19'
                              ]
                  ]
and only then pass this var to the view for visualisation. It is not a job of the view to 'modify/restructure' data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use something like this:

```
$data = [
    [
        'id'         => 1,
        'start_date' => '2014-10-17 00:00:00',
    ],
    [
        'id'         => 2,
        'start_date' => '2014-10-25 00:00:00',
    ],
    [
        'id'         => 3,
        'start_date' => '2014-11-01 00:00:00',
    ],
    [
        'id'         => 4,
        'start_date' => '2014-11-13 00:00:00',
    ],
    [
        'id'         => 5,
        'start_date' => '2014-12-16 00:00:00',
    ]
];


$month = '';

use Carbon\Carbon;

foreach ($data as $item) {
    $date = new Carbon($item['start_date']);
    if ($date->format("F") != $month) {
        $month = $date->format("F");
        echo '<h1>'.$month.'</h1>';
    }
    echo $item['id']."<br />";    
}
```

Of course it's PHP code, you can first save this data and then assign it to Blade or template in other format.

You could do it this way for Blade:

```
$data = [
    [
        'id'         => 1,
        'start_date' => '2014-10-17 00:00:00',
    ],
    [
        'id'         => 2,
        'start_date' => '2014-10-25 00:00:00',
    ],
    [
        'id'         => 3,
        'start_date' => '2014-11-01 00:00:00',
    ],
    [
        'id'         => 4,
        'start_date' => '2014-11-13 00:00:00',
    ],
    [
        'id'         => 5,
        'start_date' => '2014-12-16 00:00:00',
    ]
];


$months = '';



foreach ($data as $item) {
    $date = new Carbon($item['start_date']);
    $months[$date->format("F")][] = $item;
}
return View::make('dates')->with('months',$months);
```

And in Blade:

```
@foreach ($months as $month => $items)
   <h1>{{{ $month }}}</h1>

   @foreach ($items as $item)
    {{{ $item['id'] }}}<br />
   @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Comment: Glorious my friend. Thank you.